# The name "LikeShop" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In my code there is this error. I would like change the Image "LikeShop" when the user tapped on image. The source of the image should become from "EmpytLove.png" to "Love_tab.png"

this is my c# code:

```
    public ShopPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);
        BindingContext = new MyListViewModel();
    }
    void LikeShop_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        LikeShop.Source = "Love_tab.png";

    }
}
```

And this is my xml code :

```html
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyListCollector}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" x:Name="EmployeeListView" HasUnevenRows="true" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="Profile.png" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"/>
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding nome}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Image x:Name="LikeShop" Source="EmptyLove.png">
                                  <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                  <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="LikeShop_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: C is very different from C# or C++. Please take care when selecting proper tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**
The **Image** is in the listview .So it is unavailable by call its `name`.

**Solution:**

the event  **void LikeShop_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)**  has two parameters .And the sender here is the image that you tap.So you can get it .

```
void LikeShop_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var LikeShop= sender as Image;
    if(LikeShop.Source.ToString()=="File: Love_tab.png")
    {
       LikeShop.Source = "EmptyLove.png";
    }

    else
    {
       LikeShop.Source = "Love_tab.png";
    }
}
```

And you can remove the x:Name="xxx" from the xaml.It is unwise to use name in listview.

Comment: How can i change again the image when the user tapped? Is it possible in the same method?

Comment: Sorry, but i can't do another question because i  reached my question limit.